# UISearchBar blurry on retina

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, retina-display

[image]

Im using a UISearchBar in my iOS app, but there is some problem with the UI. If you look at this image, the icons (cross icon and search icon) inside the search bar are blurry/pixelated. I tested this on an iPhone 6 device as well. Can someone tell me if I missed something or why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you try a reboot?

Comment: yes. it still stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using a wrong tabbar icon image which was causing the search bar to be rendered like this. It looks fine after using a correct size tab bar icon image.